# Move from cloud to on-premise Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have created a dashboard on Power BI desktop, without realising that there is second version of Power BI RS for creating dashboards for an on-premise Power BI server. I have failed to upload my dashboard either as a .PBIX nor as a template .PBIT to our on-premise Power BI server. Is there any way to convert/import/migrate my work (nearly 20 hours effort) into the on-premise Power BI server without having to re-create everything again?

All this was much easier in Qliksense cloud/on-prem!

Comment: Can you open the Power BI Desktop file in Power Desktop for Report Server?

Comment: No, that fails. I can only open the .PBIX file with Power BI for Desktop, where I created it. I see no way out. I will have to create the dashboard from scratch with the Power BI for Report Server. I find it bad that there is no clear description for on-site servers implementation and deployment. Microsoft assumes cloud deployment but we have customers who reject the cloud and want only on-site.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. No solution still. Really frustrating.

Comment: Copy/paste the M code, then any DAX code (if any) and at the end copy/paste the visuals.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I am aware of to have the same report in both the PowerBI.com service and in Report Server PBIRS would be to re-build the report you created for the PowerBI.com service using "Power BI Desktop for Report Server" and have two versions.

You cannot use the PowerBI.com cloud version of Desktop to publish to PBIRS Report Server since they are different products on different versions. The PowerBI.com cloud version has features that are not available in PBIRS Report Server.